# Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'nativeElement

Tags: angular

when I have message fields added, it works, but if I have empty fields and I try to get new fields, it will receive a success message and give an error 'undefined (reading 'nativeElement')' and it doesn't fall into the error. The code is very extensive, I posted only a part and I don't know if it helps. Thanks

```html
<div>
      <button (click)="checkTableFields()">
            Get Service Fields
     </button>
</div>
```

```js
public fieldServiceFormGroup: FormGroup;
public camposServicos: any[];

@ViewChild("fieldsService", { static: false }) ngForm: NgForm;

@ViewChildren("labelFocus") labelFocus: QueryList<any>;
  Mensagens = MensagemInformativaService;

checkTableFields() {
   const control = this.campoServicoFormGroup.get("items") as FormArray;
   if (control.length < 1) {
      this.searchTableFields(true);
   } else {
      if (control.length > 0) {
         const options = {
            title: "Confirmation",
            message: `There are already fields filled in. Do you want to 
fetch more fields from the service table?`,
            textCancel: "CANCEL",
            ConfirmationText: "CONFIRM",
         };

         this.confirmationDialogService.abrir(options);

         this.confirmationDialogService.confirmation().subscribe((response) => {
            if (response) {
               this.searchTableFields(true);
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

```js
createItem() {
   return this.fb.group({
      code: "",
      service: this.serviceSelected,
      label: ["", Validators.required],
      tablefield: ["", Validators.required],
      maskField: ["", Validators.required],
      active: [true, Validators.required],
      ordering: "",
   });
}
```

```js
findTableFields(scroll: boolean) {
   this.servicesApiService
      .getFieldsTable(this._serviceSelected.cod)
      .subscribe(
         (data: Array < any > ) => {
            const control = this.fieldServicoFormGroup.get("items") as FormArray;

            data.forEach((field) => {
               control.push(this.createItemFilled(field));
               to control
                  .at(control.length - 1)
                  .get("MascaraField")
                  .setValue(this.masksFields[0]);

               if (roll) {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                     this.document.getElementById("scrollframe").scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: "smooth",
                        block: "center",
                        inline: "closest",
                     });
                  }, 500);
               }
            });
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            setTimeout(() => {
               this.labelFocus
                  .toArray()[this.fieldsServices.length].nativeElement.focus();
            }, 200);
            this.servicoMensagem.setMensagemTexto(
               "Fields added successfully. You must save changes for the fields to be 
                applied to the service."
            );
         },
         (error) => {
            this.servicoMensagem.setMensagemTexto(error);
         }
      );
}
```

**Error**

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at tab-fields-service.component.ts:292:43
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168:1)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465:1)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454:1)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650:1)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a template variable in the html so it's not finding the reference.

Comment: It's most likely due to `this.document.getElementById("scrollframe")`, it either doesn't exist or it can't find it when it runs. It's best to wait till the view is loaded before accessing it. Create an observable or something and emit to it in `findTableFields`, move the getElementById stuff to `ngAfterViewInit` in a subscription to the observable.

Comment: the problem is in that line. Although it is empty in the console.log, it is giving this error

 `.toArray()[this.fieldsServices.length].nativeElement.focus();`